# Laravel timestamps vs timestamp table and timezones

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am working on a Laravel project and I am trying to add a column to my table in a time format.
For the `created_at` and the `updated_at` the columns were created using

```php
$table->timestamps();
```

This will return time strings through an API like `'updated_at': '2023-04-27T14:39:30.000000Z'`.

Now when I try to add a new table

```php
$table->timestamp('mixed_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

it seems I can not enter the `mixed_at` time through the API in the `Y-m-dTHH:mm:ssZ` format, the problem beeing the trailing `Z`.
Without the trailing `Z` the input works fine. But I want to make sure there will not be a timezone clashes when I compare `mixed_at` to `updated_at` in the future.

Why does Laravel display the entries in the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns created with `timestamps` with a trailing `Z`. But `timestamp` tables seems blind to ISO 8601 standard entries?

Comment: [Laravel timestamps are automatically cast to Carbon objects](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#date-casting), so that value that you're seeing isn't exactly what's in the database. The mysql timestamp is just `Y-m-d H:i:s`, but you can use Laravel to mutate/cast that one as well